# Payment callback returns error: The application return value was invalid after json_decoding the return value

Tags: facebook, json, callback, payment

I'm trying to set up a purchase with credits on my facebook app.

The FB.ui() function works fine, the Payments Callback URL and the Company info is already set. My php script for the payments callback is just as the facebook developers example.

But the pay dialog does not display the confirmation dialog and the FB.ui() callback returns the error 1383046 and the error_message "Sorry, but we're having trouble processing your payment. You have not been charged for this transaction."

It happens under the payments_get_items method, so I can't test the reminder methods.

I've read a lot of posts about the same error code, but don't know if my problem could be origined in other detail that I'm not attending

This is my php script:

```
<?php

$app_secret = '***********************';

error_log($_POST['signed_request']);
// Validate request is from Facebook and parse contents for use.
$request = parse_signed_request($_POST['signed_request'], $app_secret);


// Get request type.

$request_type = $_POST['method'];

error_log($request_type, 0);

// Setup response.
$response = '';

if ($request_type == 'payments_get_items') {
// Get order info from Pay Dialog's order_info.
// Assumes order_info is a JSON encoded string.
 $order_info = json_decode($request['credits']['order_info'], true);

 // Get item id.
  $item_id = $order_info['item_id'];

  // Simulutates item lookup based on Pay Dialog's order_info.
  if ($item_id == 'real_item_id') {

$item = array(
  'title' => 'Title of my item',
  'description' => 'Description if my item',
  // Price must be denominated in credits.
  'price' => 5,
  'image_url' => 'my image url',
  'product_url' => 'my image url',
);

// Construct response.
$response = array(
           'content' => array (
               0 => $item,
               ),

            'method' => $request_type 
            );
// Response must be JSON encoded.

$response = json_encode($response);
error_log($response);
 }

} else if ($request_type == "payments_status_update") {
 // Get order details.
  $order_details = json_decode($request['credits']['order_details'], true);

  // Determine if this is an earned currency order.
 $item_data = json_decode($order_details['items'][0]['data'], true);
 $earned_currency_order = (isset($item_data['modified'])) ?
                         $item_data['modified'] : null;

 // Get order status.
  $current_order_status = $order_details['status'];

  if ($current_order_status == 'placed') {
    // Fulfill order based on $order_details unless...

    if ($earned_currency_order) {
     // Fulfill order based on the information below...
     // URL to the application's currency webpage.
     $product = $earned_currency_order['product'];
     // Title of the application currency webpage.
    $product_title = $earned_currency_order['product_title'];
    // Amount of application currency to deposit.
    $product_amount = $earned_currency_order['product_amount'];
    // If the order is settled, the developer will receive this
    // amount of credits as payment.
    $credits_amount = $earned_currency_order['credits_amount'];
   }

  $next_order_status = 'settled';

  // Construct response.
   $response = array(
              'content' => array(
                             'status' => $next_order_status,
                             'order_id' => $order_details['order_id']
                           ),
              'method' => $request_type
            );
// Response must be JSON encoded.
$response = json_encode($response);

} else if ($current_order_status == 'disputed') {
  // 1. Track disputed item orders.
  // 2. Investigate user's dispute and resolve by settling or refunding the order.
  // 3. Update the order status asychronously using Graph API.

  } else if ($current_order_status == 'refunded') {
// Track refunded item orders initiated by Facebook. No need to respond.

  } else if ($current_order_status == 'settled') {

  // Verify that the order ID corresponds to a purchase you've fulfilled, then…

  // Get order details.
   $order_details = json_decode($request['credits']['order_details'], true);

   // Construct response.
   $response = array(
              'content' => array(
                             'status' => 'settled',
                             'order_id' => $order_details['order_id']
                           ),
              'method' => $request_type
            );
  // Response must be JSON encoded.
  $response = json_encode($response);

 } else {
   // Track other order statuses.

 }
  }

// Send response.
 echo $response;

  // These methods are documented here:
  // https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/
   function parse_signed_request($signed_request, $secret) {
    list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2);

 // decode the data
 $sig = base64_url_decode($encoded_sig);
 $data = json_decode(base64_url_decode($payload), true);

 if (strtoupper($data['algorithm']) !== 'HMAC-SHA256') {
   error_log('Unknown algorithm. Expected HMAC-SHA256');
   return null;
 }

 // check sig
 $expected_sig = hash_hmac('sha256', $payload, $secret, $raw = true);
 if ($sig !== $expected_sig) {
  error_log('Bad Signed JSON signature!');
   return null;
  }

 error_log( print_r($data, true) );
 return $data;
}

function base64_url_decode($input) {
 return base64_decode(strtr($input, '-_', '+/'));
 }

 ?>
```

Looking to the error_log doc, is a fact that callback is called twice when FB.ui() function is invoked (as happens if the pay dialog doesn't receive response). But at every single call, the json object sent as var $response is correct.

My app is hosted on Heroku. The Payments Callback was first on a paid server from amazon. After that I created a free web hosting account, uploaded the script there, and directioned the payment callback url to it, but the error persists.

Is there any other aspect I need to consider???

Thanks in advance!

Note: I ommited the url's and id's from this post, but the callback script has the real information ;)